# Android: SQLite database query not returning any records

Tags: android, sqlite

I created and populated a SQLite database with the Firefox SQLite Manager. I copied the .sqlite file into the assets folder of my Android project.

My aim is to use this records to populate a spinner. When I query the database, the cursor displays the columns but no records.

My `DatabaseHandler` class extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and contains methods for `onCreate`, `onUpgrade` and `getAllOffices`.

```
public List<String> getAllOffices(){ 
    List<String> offices = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    // Select All Query 
    String selectQuery = "SELECT OfficeId as _id, OfficeName FROM " + TABLE_OFFICE; 

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 

    // looping through all rows and adding to list 
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        do { 
            offices.add(cursor.getString(1)); 
        } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
    } 

    // closing connection 
    cursor.close(); 
    db.close(); 

    // returning offices 
    return offices; 
}
```

Any ideas on why the records are not returned would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have populated it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public List<String> getAllOffices(){ 
    List<String> offices = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    // Select All Query 
    String selectQuery = "SELECT OfficeId as _id, OfficeName FROM " + TABLE_OFFICE; 

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 

    // looping through all rows and adding to list 
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        do { 
            offices.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))); 
        } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
    } 

    // closing connection 
    cursor.close(); 
    db.close(); 

    // returning offices 
    return offices; 
}
```

Basically it will just ensure that you are using the correct column index. Otherwise if you are using eclipse then try the cellobject plugin to browse the database and make sure your table is populated as expected:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cellobject-sqlite-xml-browser#.UWOU5RaBD3g

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I found that the database is not populated as expected although when I run a query on the initial database in SQLite Manager the records are there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and may be useful for you.

```
public List<String> getAllOffices(){ 
    List<String> offices = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    // Select All Query 
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_OFFICE; 

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 
    System.out.println("CURSOR SIZE:"+cursor.getCount())
    // looping through all rows and adding to list 
    if(cursor.getCount()!=0){
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
            do { 
                System.out.println(cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex("as per your db column name"));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
        }
    }   

    // closing connection 
    cursor.close(); 
    db.close(); 

    // returning offices 
    return offices; 
}
```

First of all you have to just see console output if you are getting right then add into your `office bean`